# un authenticated user must not access pages by typing in URl

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, authorization

in my web-application, an authenticated user can access this URL localhost/mydata.aspx, but an un-authenticated user type this URL he can also access this page.
so how to prevent unauthorized user from access this page and if they does redirecting them to login.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Add the following in your web.config file under the `configuration` section:

```
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>   
      </authorization>
</system.web>
```

And if you want to restrict access to a particular folder:

```
<location path="FolderPath">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

This will allow access to unauthenticate a user:

```
<location path="LoginPage.Aspx">
   <system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>  
      </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: `Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. The server may not be configured for access to the requested URL.`  this is the error, it blocks the full application if i put this in web config file

Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication methods enabled on the Web server.  Contact the Web server's administrator for additional assistance.

Comment: you need to add this in your web.config configuration section.

Comment: I have figure it out and thanks for the help but a problem now comes that an authenticated user cant also access the specific page.

Comment: yes, you can set to authentication on page level, Folder level whatever using above technique.